# Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when updating my database

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My entire code:

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, CheckFailure, has_role
import discord
import os
import random
from replit import db
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from statistics import mode
from operators import embeds
from datetime import date


#embed preset
'''
embed = discord.Embed(title="title", description="desc", color=PURPLE)
embed.set_author(name="Jäger Bot", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/816636186323189780/019dbb41d6f5b301c1fce6980d487f23.webp?size=128")
embed.add_field(name="name", value="value", inline=True)
embed.set_footer(text="requested by " + authormention + "| " + send_date)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
'''

bot = Bot(command_prefix="j!", help_command=None)

# bot ready and activity
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot started")
  game = discord.Game("with Jäger")
  await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)
# --------------------

PURPLE = 0x800080
STAFF_ROLE_ID = 817476654297383002
SOTW_ROLE_ID = 817458661982994463
FORMER_SOTW_ROLE_ID = 817030310663028736
JAGER_ROLE_ID = 818950349016137739

today = date.today()

global is_voting
is_voting = False

global send_date
send_date = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

#update db
@bot.event
async def update_db(key, value):
  if key in db.keys():
      old_value = db[key]
      old_value.append(value)
      db[key] = old_value
  else:
      db[key] = [value]
#keys:
#nominating_perons ppl who have nominated
#nominated_persons ppl who have been nominated
#voting_perons ppl who have voted
#voted_persons ppl who have been voted for

#----commands----

#help
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx ,category=None):
  print("command: help")
  staff_category = "staff"
  sotw_category = "sotw"
  misc_category = "misc"
  if category is None:
    print("no category")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Select a category with `j!help \"category\"`", description="Prefix = j!", color=PURPLE)
    embed.set_author(name="Jäger Bot | Help menu", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/816636186323189780/019dbb41d6f5b301c1fce6980d487f23.webp?size=128")
    embed.add_field(name="Categories:", value="`staff` `sotw` `misc`", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Made by ZoutigeWolf#0002 | Big thx to gang#5039 for helping")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  else:
    if category == staff_category:
      print("staffhelp")
      staff = discord.Embed(title="Staff commands", description="prefix = j!", color=PURPLE)
      staff.set_author(name="Jäger Bot | Help menu", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/816636186323189780/019dbb41d6f5b301c1fce6980d487f23.webp?size=128")
      staff.add_field(name="startvote", value="Starts the voting process", inline=False)
      staff.add_field(name="finishvote", value="Finishes the voting process", inline=False)
      staff.add_field(name="list <key> | debug only", value="Shows all the items in a specific list", inline=False)
      staff.add_field(name="clear <key> | debug only", value="Clears all the items in a specific list", inline=False)
      staff.add_field(name="ph <key> | debug only", value="Adds a `place_holder` to a specific list", inline=False)
      staff.set_footer(text="Made by ZoutigeWolf#0002 | Big thx to gang#5039 for helping")
      await ctx.send(embed=staff)
    else:
      if category == sotw_category:
        print("sotwhelp")
        sotw = discord.Embed(title="Sotw commands", description="prefix = j!", color=PURPLE)
        sotw.set_author(name="Jäger Bot | Help menu", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/816636186323189780/019dbb41d6f5b301c1fce6980d487f23.webp?size=128")
        sotw.add_field(name="nominate <member>", value="Nominate a member", inline=False)
        sotw.add_field(name="vote <member>", value="Vote for a member", inline=False)
        sotw.set_footer(text="Made by ZoutigeWolf#0002 | Big thx to gang#5039 for helping")
        await ctx.send(embed=sotw)
      else:
        if category == misc_category:
          print("mischelp")
          misc = discord.Embed(title="Misc commands", description="prefix = j!", color=PURPLE)
          misc.set_author(name="Jäger Bot | Help menu", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/816636186323189780/019dbb41d6f5b301c1fce6980d487f23.webp?size=128")
          misc.add_field(name="quote", value="A random siege operator quote", inline=False)
          misc.add_field(name="profile <operator>", value="Shows the profile of the specified siege operator", inline=True)
          misc.add_field(name="shoot <member>", value="Shoot someone", inline=False)
          misc.add_field(name="sexy <member>", value="Shows how sexy someone is", inline=False)
          misc.set_footer(text="Made by ZoutigeWolf#0002 | Big thx to gang#5039 for helping")
          await ctx.send(embed=misc)
        else:
          print("wrong category")
          embed = discord.Embed(title="Select a category with `j!help \"category\"`", description="Prefix = j!", color=PURPLE)
          embed.set_author(name="Jäger Bot | Help menu", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/816636186323189780/019dbb41d6f5b301c1fce6980d487f23.webp?size=128")
          embed.add_field(name="Categories:", value="`staff` `sotw` `miscellaneous`", inline=True)
          embed.set_footer(text="Made by ZoutigeWolf#0002 | Big thx to gang#5039 for helping")
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
#help end

#SOTW
#nominate
@bot.command()
async def nominate(ctx, nominatedperson: discord.Member):
  print("command: nominate")
  print(nominatedperson)
  nominated_person = nominatedperson.mention
  nominating_person = ctx.author.mention
  former_sotw_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=FORMER_SOTW_ROLE_ID)
  if not is_voting:
    print("is_voting was false")
    nominated_persons = db["nominated_persons"]
    nominating_persons = db["nominating_persons"]
    if nominating_person not in nominating_persons:
      print("nominating person wasnt in nominating persons")
      if nominated_person in nominated_persons:
        print("nominated_person was in nominated_persons")
        await ctx.send("That member has already been nominated!")
      else:
        print("nominated_person wasnt in nominated_persons")
        former_sotw_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=FORMER_SOTW_ROLE_ID)
        if former_sotw_role in nominatedperson.roles:
          print("nominated_person was former sotw")
          await ctx.send("That member has already been SOTW this year!")
        else:
          print("nominated_person wasnt former sotw")
          embed = discord.Embed(title="Member nominated:", description=nominated_person, color=PURPLE)
          embed.set_author(name="Jäger Bot", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/816636186323189780/019dbb41d6f5b301c1fce6980d487f23.webp?size=128")
          embed.add_field(name="By:", value=nominating_person, inline=True)
          embed.set_footer(text=send_date)
          print(nominated_persons)
          await update_db(nominated_persons, nominated_person)
          await update_db(nominating_persons, nominating_person)
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      print("nominating_person was in nominating_persons")
      await ctx.send("You already nominated someone")
  else:
    print("is_voting was true")
    await ctx.send("You can't nominate while we are voting for the next SOTW!")
#nominate end
#SOTW end

#insert place_holder
@bot.command()
@has_role(STAFF_ROLE_ID)
async def ph(ctx, key):
  print("command: ph")
  await update_db(key, "place_holder")
  await ctx.send("Placeholder has been added to " + key)

@ph.error
async def ph_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
    await ctx.send("Only staff members can use this command")
#insert place_holder end

#list
@bot.command()
@has_role(STAFF_ROLE_ID)
async def list(ctx, to_list):
  print("command: list")
  if to_list in db.keys():
    requester = ctx.author
    requestermention = str(requester)
    items = db[to_list]
    embed = discord.Embed(title="List", description=to_list, color=PURPLE)
    embed.set_author(name="Jäger Bot", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/816636186323189780/019dbb41d6f5b301c1fce6980d487f23.webp?size=128")
    embed.add_field(name="Items:", value=items, inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="requested by " + requestermention + " | " + send_date)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  else:
    await ctx.send("That list doesn't exist")

@list.error
async def list_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
    await ctx.send("Only staff members can use this command")
#list end

#list keys
@bot.command()
async def keys(ctx):
  allkeys = db.keys()
  await ctx.send(allkeys)
#list keys end

#clear
@bot.command()
@has_role(STAFF_ROLE_ID)
async def clear(ctx, to_clear):
  print("command: clear")
  str_userid = ctx.author.id
  str_zoutigewolfid = "298516275322290188"
  userid = int(str_userid)
  zoutigewolfid = int(str_zoutigewolfid)
  if userid == zoutigewolfid:
    if to_clear in db.keys():
      del db[to_clear]
      await ctx.send("List " + to_clear + " has been cleared")
    else:
      await ctx.send("That list doesn't exist")
  else:
    await ctx.send("Only my daddy Wolf can use this command!")

@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
    await ctx.send("Only staff members can use this command")
#clear end

#quote
# preset {"title": "", "description": ""},
quotes_list = [
{"title": "A really big fucking hole coming right up!", "description": "Jordan 'Thermite' Trace"},
{"title": "Pass those plates around!", "description":"Julien 'Rook' Nizan"},
{"title": "You can stop worrying about grenades now!", "description": "Marius 'Jäger' Streicher"},
{"title": "if it runs on batteries, I'll see it!", "description": "Monica 'IQ' Weiss"},
{"title": "Fookin' laser sights!", "description": "Mike 'Thatcher' Baker"},
{"title": "Toxic babes are in position!", "description": "James 'Smoke' Porter"},
{"title": "Jammah in position!", "description": "Mark 'Mute' R. Chandar"},
{"title": "EDD primed, let them come!", "description": "Maxim 'Kapkan' Basuda"},
{"title": "Mine flying out!", "description": "Elżbieta 'Ela' Bosak"},
{"title": "You're mine bloody asshole!", "description": "Taina 'Caveira' Pereira"},
{"title": "Malbodan haengdong-iji (말보단 행동이지)", "description": "Chul 'Vigil' Kyung Hwa"},
{"title": "Launching override!", "description": "Grace 'Dokkaebi' Nam"},
{"title": "Camera in position!", "description": "Meghan 'Valkyrie' J. Castellano"},
{"title": "As my friend would say: A really big fucking hole coming right up.", "description": "Yumiko 'Hibana' Imagawa"},
{"title": "Big brother coming in for overwatch!", "description": "Olivier 'Lion' Flament"},
{"title": "Time for a wakeup call", "description": "Grace 'Dokkaebi' Nam"},
{"title": "No runnin' in the halls!", "description": "Morowa 'Clash' Evans"},
{"title": "LMG mounted and loaded!", "description": "Alexsandr 'Tachanka' Senaviev, RIP old tachanka"},
{"title": "Rtila active!", "description": "Jalal 'Kaid' El Fassi"},
{"title": "Now you see me, now you don't!", "description": "Elena 'Mira' María Álvarez"},
{"title": "Why do it yourself when robots do it better?", "description": "Masaru 'Echo' Enatsu"},
{"title": "Bullseye, got us a drone", "description": "Max 'Mozzie' Goose"},
]

@bot.command()
async def quote(ctx):
  requester = ctx.author
  requestermention = str(requester)
  random_index = random.randint(0,21)
  quote = quotes_list[random_index]
  embed = discord.Embed(**quote, color=PURPLE)
  embed.set_footer(text="Requested by " + requestermention + " | " + send_date)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
#quote end

#operator profile
@bot.command()
async def profile(ctx, operator_name):
  await ctx.send(embed=embeds[operator_name])
#operator profile end

#sexy
@bot.command()
async def sexy(ctx, person: discord.Member):
  jager_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=JAGER_ROLE_ID)
  sexyperson = person.mention
  if jager_role in person.roles:
    print("person was jager")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Sexy meter", description="Lord Jäger is 69420% sexy", color=PURPLE)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  else:
    print("person wasnt jager")
    outputint = random.randint(0,100)
    output = str(outputint)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Sexy meter", description=sexyperson + " is " + output + "% sexy", color=PURPLE)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
#sexy end

#gun list
guns_list = [
  "MP5",
  "M4",
  "AK-47",
  "MP7",
  "SCAR-L",
  "Desert Eagle",
  "MP5K",
  "AUG A2",
  "M249",
  "AR15"
]

#title list
title_list = [
  "Elimination",
  "Homicide",
  "Assasination",
  "Drive-by",
  "Sniped",
  "Popped",
  "Capped",
  "No-scoped",
]
#shoot
@bot.command()
async def shoot(ctx, person: discord.Member):
  print("command: shoot")
  shooter = ctx.author.mention
  shotperson = person.mention
  shooterid = ctx.author.id
  shotpersonid = person.id
  randomnumber = random.randint(0,9)
  randomgun = guns_list[randomnumber]
  randomtitlenumber = random.randint(0,7)
  title = title_list[randomtitlenumber]
  if shooterid != shotpersonid:
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=shooter + " shot " + shotperson + " with " + randomgun, color=PURPLE)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  else:
    await ctx.send("Shooting yourself is a very dumb idea")
#shoot end

#anti nword
racist_words = [
    "nigga",
    "niggas",
    "nigger",
    "niggers",
    "/Vigga",
    "/Viggas",
    "/Vigger",
    "/Viggers",
    "niga",
    "nega",
    "negga",
    "nibba",
    "/vigga",
    "/viggas",
    "/vigger",
    "/viggers",
]

# racist detector 9000
"""
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if any(word in msg.content for word in racist_words):
        print("someone said the n word")
        await msg.channel.send(msg.author.mention + " did you just seriously say the n-word?")
        await msg.channel.send("Not poggers bro, not poggers")
        await msg.channel.send(f"<@&{STAFF_ROLE_ID}> come get this bitch")
        await msg.delete()
        await bot.process_commands(msg)
"""
#racist end
#commands end

keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

when i do the command j!nominate @discord mention it gives the error "Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" but dont remember hashing any list. can someone please tell me why this is happening? the database is formatted like this ["1", "2", "3"] if you need to know

error:

```
Ignoring exception in command nominate:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 148, in nominate
    await update_db(nominated_persons, nominated_person)
  File "main.py", line 53, in update_db
    db[key] = [value]
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 182, in __setitem__
    r = self.sess.post(self.db_url, data={key: j})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND THE ANSWER!
the problem was with `await update_db(nominated_persons, nominated_person)`
as it is like that, it doesn't update the db because `nominated_persons` is undefined, so i defined it with `nominated_persons = db["nominated_persons"]`. but then i would get the hash error because that is a list and i cant use that, so i just did `nominated_persons = "nominated_persons"` so the nominated_persons is defined as the word "nominated_persons". so now it works

i feel so stupid

here is the updated code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def nominate(ctx, nominatedperson: discord.Member):
  print("command: nominate")
  nominated_person = nominatedperson.mention
  nominated_persons = "nominated_persons"
  await update_db(nominated_persons, nominated_person)
  await ctx.send("whatever")
```

(Side note: you can just put “nominated_persons” in the update_db command you don’t have to refer to it with a variable like i did.)

Answer (score 0):

Untested but try the following

```py
async def update_db(key, value):
  if key in db.keys():
      db[key].append(value)
  else:
      db[key] = [value]
```

Can you see why you were getting the TypeError by comparing my code with yours?

Comment: I tried it and i got the exact same error:

Comment: i posted the whole error in the post, line numbers arent correct

Comment: Edit your question to include the full traceback and not as a comment. Show also your updated code. You're overwriting `key` with the value which is a list.

Comment: You haven't show the updated code. You still have the same buggy code.The root cause is this line `key = db[key]`.

Comment: sorry, im new to this, i added the whole updated code and the whole error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for updating the question with the full code and traceback.

The offending line is `db[key] = [value]` that throws a `TypeError`:*`unhashable type list`*,
which means you passed a **list type** as key argument for the `update_db` function.

That cannot be done because, as the traceback clearly states, **you cannot hash a list type** (meaning you cannot access a dictionary value using a key that is a list type).

But the real source of the pain is right above that line:

```
if key in db.keys():
      key = db[key]
      key.append(value)
      db[key] = key
```

That's a lot of `key`, isn't it? The problem here is that you used the variable name `key` referring to different things and you ended up with a bit of confusion, so I suggest you use different variables to indicate different things:

```
async def update_db(key, value):
  if key in db.keys():
      old_value = db[key]
      old_value.append(value)
      db[key] = old_value
  else:
      db[key] = [value]
```

In this way it is the `value` that is actually updated in the database and not the `key`, so the latter would never end up being a list.

This last one is just out of curiosity. Why are you defining a function to update the database, aren't there defined methods to do that? What db are you using?

Comment: I'm using repl.it for coding this bot so i'm also using their database, I tried using your code and i still got the same error